# "Punta riversa": An Oxford Latin Dictionary Analysis

Tags: reference-request, latin

I am etymologizing the word *punta riversa*, and I would like to request a photocopy--or resource link--to the Oxford Latin Dictionary's entries for both *punctum* and *reversus*. Thank you.

Also, is [*reuersio*](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-4iaGl-MmPxs/UTglHYOgKYI/AAAAAAAAAQE/JNglAlwgTv8/w228-h305-o-k/photo%2B4.JPG) what I should be looking for in the OLD? Why the *u* and not the *v*?

Comment: Punctum and reversus are Latin words - I don't know how the OED might help you. What you need is an etymological dictionary of Latin, e.g. de Vaan or Walde or Ernout & Meillet.

Comment: @AlexB. Oh, the OED isn't helpful. I'm on the online version now. That is why I typed "OLD." What I meant was "Oxford Latin Dictionary" rather than "Oxford English Dictionary."

Comment: It has to be the OLD.

Comment: Have you tried Amazon? http://www.amazon.com/Oxford-Latin-Dictionary-P-Glare/dp/0198642245 You can search for the words you need there. It worked for me. Also, you could look them up in Lewis and Short or Forcellini - both are open-access.

Comment: @AlexB. Below are links to the entries:

[LINK 1](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-c91FhTJjUk4/UTgkwbi4yJI/AAAAAAAAAPs/nYSj0UkC3jI/s630/photo+1.JPG)  
[LINK 2](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-5biK9dQ1h0w/UTgk4PY5s3I/AAAAAAAAAP0/AmgFs31V-zU/s630/photo+2.JPG)  
[LINK 3](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-WhufplQbn88/UTgk_p4Nd8I/AAAAAAAAAP8/E5KGlXznIPI/s630/photo+3.JPG)  
[LINK 4](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-4iaGl-MmPxs/UTglHYOgKYI/AAAAAAAAAQE/JNglAlwgTv8/s630/photo+4.JPG)

Comment: [This is a Latin-Italian dictionary](http://www.dizionario-latino.com/)... It translates to italian but you might understand it if you know some Latin. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, *reuersio* is what you want to look up. Here's my first-order approximation of why this is so — I trust that it is not too inaccurate!

The [classical Latin alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet#Classical_Latin_alphabet) had only the letters

*A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, V, X, Y, Z,*

where *I* represented both /i/ and /j/ and *V* represented both /u/ and /w/; by the Middle Ages, the Latin alphabet had also acquired more-or-less the now-familiar lower-case forms

*a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, x, y, z.*

However, *j* and *v* only appeared still later, as allographs of *i* and *u*, respectively, and it wasn't until after the Renaissance that *i* and *j* systematically represented /i/ and (what had at least been) /j/, respectively (e.g., *cujus* for *cuius*), and *u* and *v* systematically represented /u/ and (what had at least been) /w/ (e.g., *vos* for *uos*).

At any rate, since the Latin orthography of classical antiquity only knew *I* and *V* (which originally gave rise to the lower case forms *i* and *u*), many modern editions and references use only upper-case *I* with lower case *i* and upper-case *V* with lower-case *u*, (I presume) in order to adhere as much as possible to the original orthography whilst allowing for the normal use of upper- and lower-case letters.